# Do the 'continue' and 'break' statements work with a for...in?

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop

The title says it all, to confirm the current question in a more formal manner:

Do the 'continue' and 'break' statements work with a for...in loop in JavaScript?

I have tried using a label with my for...in loop but it breaks the application outright...if I cannot do this is there anything else I can do?

I need this functionality because I am error checking and if an error is found regarding the current item I want to report this error then continue to the next item. Solutions using pure JavaScript preferred if possible.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Why didn't you try instead of asking ? It would have been faster.

Comment: I did...my continue statement isn't working...so I thought I would ask...I have added a label to my for...in loop and after the error added 'continue label;' but it breaks the program...

Comment: Here is a good explenation about the differences between the 'continue' and the 'break' : statements in javascript :http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp

Comment: @Örvar: I have seen that thanks...it was my original reference to do it...my `continue label;` still isn't working...bearing in mind I have not done this before but it looks right...

Comment: @user1360809: Then show us your code, please!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. They do.

```
for(var i in window){
   break;
   console.log(i);
}
```

Prints nothing.

If we check [the language specification](http://es5.github.io/#x12.8) we can see that:

Break is evaluated as: `Return (break, empty, empty).`

Which terminates the current block.

More generally - it'll work with a block:

```
{
    break; // this works, no alert
    alert("HI");   
}

while(true){
    break; // this works, no alert
    alert("HI");   
}

for(var fake in window){
    break; // this works, no alert
    alert("HI");   
}
```

Comment: can you comment on the use of the `continue` statement using labels with a for...in? Thanks!

Comment: @user1360809 Chances are - you shouldn't be using labels or a `continue` in a `for.. in` but the point was that they work in for... in (just like break!) as they do in any block.

Comment: @user1360809 Did this answer solve your issue? If it did not, how can I improve it?

Answer (score 0):

Absolute Yes.
Very easy to try on Firebug.